# how to delay insertBefore() in jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to use insertBefore() function 2 times, so i need to delay the second one. Is there any way I can do it?

```
<button>Click</button>

<br><br>
<p id="p1">This is a paragraph1.</p>
<p id="p2">This is a paragraph2.</p>
<p id="p3">This is a paragraph3.</p>

</body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("button").click(function(){

             $("#p3").insertBefore("#p2");
             $("#p3").delay(1000000).insertBefore("#p1"); 
        });});
</script>
```

Comment: jQuery's `delay()` is intended for animations, not DOM methods.

Just use a timeout instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `setTimeout();`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
       $("#p3").insertBefore("#p2");
       setTimeout(function(){
         $("#p3").insertBefore("#p1"); 
         }, 1000);
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/Lxph68g7/)

Comment: @dummy you r Welcome .. Good Luck :)