# How to set fixed time for preloader

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, preloader

I want to set a fixed time in my preloader for my website. Because after preloading image I can't see any animation in my home section.

```
 $(window).load(function() { 
            $('#preloader').fadeOut(); 
            $('.preloader_img').delay(150).fadeOut('slow');     
});
```

Thanks

Comment: jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/onst22m6/ for full preloader code.

Comment: use setTimeout  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33316009/how-to-delay-insertbefore-in-jquery/33316071#33316071

Comment: Sorry I am not jquery expert. I don't know how to set setTimeout function.

Comment: I already sent you a link .. and you will find a Demo in it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surround the code with a `setTimeout()` function, like so:

```
setTimeout(function(){        
    $('#preloader').fadeOut();
    $('.preloader_img').delay(150).fadeOut('slow'); 
}, 10000);
```

Change 10000 with whatever amount you want in milliseconds and remember 1000 milliseconds equals 1 second.

Comment: Sorry , Did not work :(

Comment: @AshrafulHaque, updated answer. How about now?

Comment: Did you downvote my answer?

Comment: @PraveenKumar,  What answer?

Comment: Thanks everyone. Specially to King and Praveen Kumar.